# Given two Numbers, Finding Relation to third

Tags: relations

I'm trying to find the relation of three numbers. I know that two numbers have a relation that equate to the third. The tricky part is that they don't have to equal the third number exactly,but should be very close ($\pm 5$).

The data I've collected so far is

```
341 = 11, 31
357 = 10, 157
383 = 9, 242
525 = 7, 57
501 = 7, 146
365 = 10, 100
```

These have to do with computer programming so I figured adding/multiplying one of the numbers by $256$ might be involved, but I cannot figure it out.  Is there a way to figure out the relationship of numbers like this?

Comment: If you describe how the numbers relate to computer science, a user here might see something useful. [You say you "collected data so far" so there must be some way you did the collecting.]